# Compatibility issue between Hbase 0.94.2 and apache nutch dependency

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, nutch

I am trying to install apache nutch 2.2.1 and have successfully build it after making the required changes in the configuration files by following http://www.blogjava.net/paulwong/archive/2013/08/31/403513.html tutorial. But even after building it I am not able to crawl anything and after hours of inspection I realized that the hbase version on my company cluster is Hbase- 0.94.2 whereas the installation dependency for  apache nutch 2.2.1 is HBase 0.90.4. As hbase-0.90.4.jar is not compatible with Hbase- 0.94.2 I am getting the following error when I try to inject the url into nutch.  Kindly help me in changing the dependency of the apache nutch or fixing the error.

## I am posting  the error below.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: ï¿½-11562@bt13acl1node26.comp.comï¿½$3ï¿½¿½bt13acl1node26.comp.com,60000,1401268790838
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:127)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
        ... 12 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a host:port pair: ï¿½-11562@bt13acl1node26.comp.comï¿½$3ï¿½¿½bt13acl1node26.comp.com,60000,1401268790838
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HServerAddress.(HServerAddress.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterAddressTracker.getMasterAddress(MasterAddressTracker.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:109)
        ... 14 more

Answer (score 1):

You installed Apache Nutch 2.2.1 it uses Apache Gora 0.3 which only supports old Apache HBase 0.90.x as it stated in the [official docs](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial).

Anyway you still can use Nutch 2.2.x using the following workaround:

1. Clone, configure and build fresh [Nutch from the official Git branch 2.x](https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/2.x) as it migrated to Gora 0.4 which compatible with Apache HBase 0.94.x.
2. Clone and build [my version of Apache HBase 0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0](https://github.com/dobromyslov/hbase/releases/tag/0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0) to use it with the latest Apache Hadoop 2.5.0.

Similar issue was created for [Apache Gora 0.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GORA-304) project. They don't plan to upgrade Apache HBase dependency to the fresh one in the nearest future.

You can also read [compatibility documentation for Apache HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/book/configuration.html) to figure out how to build your own version for any Hadoop release.

Apache Nutch was tested and works well with the following stack:

- Apache Nutch from 2.x git branch which uses Gora 0.4;
- Apache Hbase 0.94.24-hadoop-2.5.0;
- Apache Hadoop 2.5.0.

Comment: this version completely explains what's caused the original issue.